# Entity column named not found in Springboot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I am using SpringBoot and I have an entity class which has some values like:

```java
private int a;
private String b;
private int c;

@Column(nullable = true)
private int d;
```

I am using a native query in my repository and I am adding a new column to that query with "as" keyword. Like for example:

a+c as d.

When I executed this native query I have got an error with "column d not found in the table t".

Comment: Please, add a full query example with class and param names. What do you mean *I am adding a new column to that query*?

Comment: I mean like in the sql
Select (a + c) as d I mean it is simple SQL as usage I got an error in the entity side it says there is no d field in the table t and it's right I don't have column d and don't want to add that.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that exception from 'that' query? JPA cannot use that entity as it is defined if there is no 'd' column in the database, so I don't know why you would try defining it that way. Try a constructor query, where you provide a java class with a constructor that can take in your data types to let JPA build it instead of trying to build entities that it must manage on a column that doesn't exist. Otherwise, show the code and the query exactly as you've defined and are executing it through JPA/Spring.

Comment: I am using a nested sql query I have some other tables too I am getting a variable from nested query and in the sql I can name it with "as" keyword that means I can see an extra value that is not placed in my t table. I want to get this value and use it in the spring boot. I did some research I believe I need something like "Transient" but it does not working as expected it's always returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a, ' ', c) AS d FROM t
```

Could you also share the exact query that you were using to get that data?

Comment: I am using a nested sql query I have some other tables too I am getting a variable from nested query and in the sql I can name it with "as" keyword that means I can see an extra value that is not placed in my t table. I want to get this value and use it in the spring boot. I did some research I believe I need something like "Transient" but it does not working as expected it's always return 0